# Can I connect two routers set up as Access Points (AP) to a Gigabit switch?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

Existing network setup is ISP modem > Dell SonicWall TZ105 firewall (setup as DHCP server) > gigabit switch > WRT 1900AC (DHCP disabled).  Other devices such as a network printer and two NAS devices are also connected to the gigabit switch.  We are endeavouring to enhance wireless coverage in a fairly large two story building with complex infrastructure, e.g. concrete walls in certain spots.

Can a second router (a WRT 54g) be added to the gigabit switch (DHCP disabled, different IP but same SSID)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Set the 2nd AP to a different channel than the first one.  Since the APs are set up as bridges, your clients will keep the same IP as they roam from one AP to the other.  This is a very common way of doing things.